# C# Download Method - System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format'

Tags: c#, methods, label, progress-bar

I'm new to programming in C# and im trying to create an Async downloader because WebClient is just to slow for a 500mb+ zip file. Below is the code I'm working with and these are the lines im having issues with updating my progressbar and label

PROBLEM CODE:

```
if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Show()));
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Show()));
                                progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                            }

                            if (labelProgress.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Show()));
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString()));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Show()));
                                labelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString();
                            }
```

CODE

```
private void Downloader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Downloader.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Downloader.Enabled = true;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadFileWithProgress(zipUrl, zipPath, progressBar, labelPerc);
        }
        private void DownloadFileWithProgress(string DownloadLink, string TargetPath, Bunifu.UI.Winforms.BunifuProgressBar progressBar, Label labelProgress)
        {
            int bytesProcessed = 0;
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            WebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
                if (request != null)
                {
                    double TotalBytesToReceive = 0;
                    var SizewebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(DownloadLink));
                    SizewebRequest.Method = "HEAD";

                    using (var webResponse = SizewebRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        var fileSize = webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Lenght");
                        TotalBytesToReceive = Convert.ToDouble(fileSize);
                    }

                    response = request.GetResponse();
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        string filePath = TargetPath;
                        localStream = File.Create(filePath);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = 0;

                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
                            double bytesIn = double.Parse(bytesProcessed.ToString());
                            double percentage = bytesIn / TotalBytesToReceive * 100;
                            percentage = Math.Round(percentage, 0);

                            if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Show()));
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Show()));
                                progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                            }

                            if (labelProgress.InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Show()));
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString()));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Show()));
                                labelProgress.Text = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()).ToString();
                            }
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null) response.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: On which line does the exception occur? Note that e.g. `Convert.ToDouble` is culture-senstitive, maybe you have to specify `CulturInfo.InvariantCulture` for the conversion.

Comment: The first one begins with ```progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())));```

Comment: Why do you transform this to a string and then parse it back to a number? Why not just `(int)Math.Truncate(percentage)`.

Comment: @KlausGütter - I get this error when I do that ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'``` on this line ```labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Text = (int)Math.Truncate(percentage)));```

Comment: Sure, here you need percentage.ToString()

Comment: I have set ```progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value = (int)Math.Truncate(percentage)));``` & ```labelProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => labelProgress.Text = percentage.ToString()));``` I dont get any errors but the label and progressbar arent updating.

Comment: Dear demo7up I have written an awesome downloader with resume support and asynchronous behavior on github. You can use and extend it for free :) https://github.com/amiru3f/deathnight-downloader

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this package -> https://github.com/bezzad/Downloader